# Check if a tree is symmetric (about its center) possibly without using a Class

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, tree, graph-algorithm

I have always seen algorithms ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56718064/techniques-used-in-checking-if-a-binary-tree-is-symmetric) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436623/check-if-a-binary-tree-is-a-mirror-image-or-symmetric?rq=1) for eg.) that do the Symmetric tree check but they always cater to Binary trees. The algorithm essentially is : use two variables (pointers) that stays symmetric about the center while it traverses and if at any point, they do not correspond to the same node_value, you return False. Finally, Return True.

**So given an adjacency list (the input can be as V denoting the number of vertices and then (u,v) pairs denoting the edges where u -> v), how do I implement the algorithm for a generic tree? One that does not require the concept of classes would help me, unless impossible to do that way.** As for the tree definition, assume that the root node will be given as input and the order in which the elements are entered will represent the order of the children. For example, [[..],[..],[1,4,3],[..]] corresponds to node_2 having  three children 1,4,3 with node_1 being the left-most child, node_4 the middle one and node_3 the right-most child.

I would prefer to get help in writing a code in Python; otherwise pseudocode (a rough sketch of the implementation, at least) helps and I will google up the necessary things.

Comment: Surely, when you have to check whether a tree is symmetric, you have ... a tree. Which is the tree's data structure? But then you seem to ask what could be a data structure for a generic tree... That is a different question. Please focus on one question only.

Comment: @trincot Could you tell me if it is more focussed now?

Comment: It is, but how will you know which node is the root of the tree? Secondly, is there any order in the children of a node? If not, then what defines "symmetric"?

Comment: @trincot We will simply input the root node. If you have an adjacency list and a connected tree graph, it takes linear time to find out out the root anyway. Call a tree symmetric if the left and the right sub-tree of the root node are mirror images of one another. For a more mathematical definition, consider the tree T(V,E) and the function f : V' \times {L,R} -> V such that f(..f(f(node,x1),x2,...x_j) = f(..f(f(node,x'1),x'2,...x'_j) where x_i != x'_i \in {L,R}. where V' = V \ {vertices having no child}, L,R respecticaly correspond to Left, Right (ie, node.L denotes the left child of node).

Comment: *"Call a tree symmetric if the left and the right sub-tree ..."*: yes, but I thought the reason of your question was to extend this to non-binary trees, but now you come back to them. My point is: the adjacency list as you described it above does not define what is left or right. That's why I asked about *order*. Do you have any attempt at defining a tree in python? I get the feeling your question is still double: (1) how to define a tree in Python; (2) how to check that tree is symmetric. There should be just one question. If it is (2), then please show your code for representing a tree.

Comment: @trincot Technically, it is (2) and you can assume that the Left is the child that is entered first and Right the other one. The main reason why it might still look like I am asking for (1) as well is because I am not familiar with Classes/Objects, which is why I mentioned "...that does not require the concept of Classes..". I am sorry I do not know how to define a tree in Python. I will read the answer below to get a fair bit of idea; I will read it in some time.

Comment: So, technically it is (1) and (2) you are asking. That makes this question too broad.

Comment: @trincot I did not ask (1) anywhere. I didn't ask for a tree definition. I asked if a tree is entered in the form of an adj list and the order of entry denotes the order of children from left to right, is it possible to check if a tree is symmetric without the usage of a class? (Perhaps you can traverse an array from the left for a node on the left and traverse from the right for a node on the right, or something similar). I have added something right after the bold text in the original question.

Comment: OK, with that addition to your question it is clear how you represent a tree in Python. I have posted an answer that is based on that data structure.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot write code with a "generic tree".  We need an implementation.

Here is a quick implementation of a tree in Python.  (Sorry, but it is a class.)  It allows each node to have an arbitrary number of children.  No matter what shape your tree has, this will represent it.  (And if you create a loop, it will break.)

```
class Tree:
    def __init__ (self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.children = []

    def add_child (self, child):
        if isinstance(child, type(self)):
            self.children.append(child)
        else:
            self.children.append(type(self)(child))

    def __str__(self, indent = ""):
        result = indent + "- " + str(self.value) + '\n'
        if 0 < len(self.children):
            return result + "".join(
                [child.__str__(indent + "  ") for child in self.children])
        else:
            return result
```

Here is a quick demonstration of building a tree then printing it.

```
t = Tree(4)
t.add_child(5)
t.add_child(6)
t.children[1].add_child(7)
print(t)
```

Which will print:

```
- 4
  - 5
  - 6
    - 7
```

Now here is a check for symmetric trees.  It is exactly like binary trees except instead of walking the children left/right vs right/left you have to use a loop with indices going one way with one and the other with the other.  Luckily Python makes this easy because negative subscripts go from the end.  But there is an off-by-one issue - the left-most element is at 0 while the rightmost element is at 1.

```
# t1 goes right to left, t2 goes left to right.
def is_symmetric (t1, t2=None):
    if t2 is None:
        t2 = t1
    if t1.value != t2.value:
        return False
    elif len(t1.children) != len(t2.children):
        return False
    else:
        for i in range(len(t1.children)):
            if not is_symmetric(t1.children[i], t2.children[-i-1]):
                return False
    return True
```

The example tree that I gave above was not symmetric, here is one that is.

```
t = Tree(4)
t.add_child(1)
t.add_child(2)
t.add_child(2)
t.add_child(1)
t.children[1].add_child(0)
t.children[1].add_child(3)
t.children[2].add_child(3)
t.children[2].add_child(0)
```

Also note that symmetric as a binary tree need not match symmetric as an arbitrary tree like this.  Here is a trivial example.

```
 t = Tree(4)
 t.add_child(3)
 t.children[0].add_child(2)
 t.children[0].children[0].add_child(1)
```

This tree is a chain.  In a binary tree you have to choose whether to go left or right and it can't be made symmetric.  But in this representation it is symmetric.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I will read it in sometime. I upvoted it to neutralize the downvote it was initially met with; please do not take it down.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take this tree as example. Nodes are identified by a number:

```
            _________0_________
           /         |         \
          1          2          3
         / \       / | \       / \  
        4   5    6   7   8    9   10
        |       / \     / \        |
       11      12 13   14 15      16
```

This can be encoded in the following adjacency list (directed edges going "down"):

```
adj = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [9, 10],
    [11],
    [],
    [12, 13],
    [],
    [14, 15],
    [],
    [16],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    []
]
```

One way to do this, is to create a generator that performs a depth-first traversal and yields a 1 when it goes down in the tree, and 2 when it goes up. It could then yield a 3 when the traversal is complete:

```
def dfs(adj, sense=1, root=0):
    for child in adj[root][::sense]:
        yield 1  # Indicate that we move down in the tree
        yield from dfs(adj, sense, child)  # recurse...
        yield 2  # Indicate that we up up in the tree
    yield 3  # Indicate that we arrived back at the root.
```

The actual values 1, 2 and 3 are freely chosen. The only requirement is that they are different from eachother.

The `sense` parameter determines whether children are traversed in their proper order ("left to right"), or in reversed order ("right to left").

With this in place, it is easy to check whether the tree is symmetric. Perform two, opposite-directed traversals in tandem, each time verifying that the next yielded value is the same in both traversals:

```
def is_symmetric(adj, root=0):
    a_iter = dfs(adj, 1, root)  # get iterator for the "left-to-right" traversal
    for b in dfs(adj, -1, root):  # traverse "right-to-left"
        if b != next(a_iter):  # verify that both traversals give the same value
            return False
    return True
```

Using `zip` and `all` you can write that function as:

```
def is_symmetric(adj, root=0):
    return all(a == b for a, b in zip(dfs(adj, 1, root), dfs(adj, -1, root)))
```

There is no risk that a difference will go undetected when one tree has fewer nodes than the other, as then `a` or `b` will at a certain point get value 3, different from the 1 or 2 coming from the other tree. And so `all` will return False.

Call the function as follows:

```
print(is_symmetric(adj))  # True for the example above.
```